# How can I save rsform for later ? [Solution]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, joomla

I've got it some solutions for people who need it save and continue rsform for later.

You will need it add the jquery library and cookie addon (https://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/) to your site.

Next you need it paste this to javascript area:

```js
    $('document').ready(function(){

        $('input[type="text"], textarea').each (
            function(index){  
                var field = $(this).attr("id");
                $(this).val($.cookie(field));
            }
        );

        $('input[type="radio"]').each(
            function(index){  
                var field = $(this).attr("name");
                if($.cookie(field)) {
                    var value = $.cookie(field);
                    $("[id='"+value+"']").prop('checked',true);
                }
            }
        );

        $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(
            function(index){  
                var field = $(this).attr("name");
                if($.cookie(field)) {
                    var value = $.cookie(field);
                    $("[id='"+value+"']").prop('checked',true);
                }
            }
        );

        $('input[type="text"], textarea').on('input', function() {
            var Uniq = $(this).attr("id");
            var Content = $(this).val();
            $.removeCookie(Uniq);
                 $.cookie(Uniq, Content);
        });

        $('input:radio').on('change', function() {
            var Uniq = $(this).attr("name");
            var Content = $(this).attr("id");
            $.removeCookie(Uniq);
                $.cookie(Uniq, Content);
        });


        $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
            var Uniq = $(this).attr("name");
            var Content = $(this).attr("id");
            $.removeCookie(Uniq);
                $.cookie(Uniq, Content);
        }); 
    });
```

Script will save the text input, radio input, checkbox input and textarea to session cookie and next will fill your form. Enjoy!

If you want to save for more time then the browser session, put count of days here $.cookie(Uniq, Content, { expires : 10 }); // 10 days

---

THE OTHER SECURE SOLUTION WITHOUT USING COOKIE WE CAN USE LOCALSTORAGE OF WEBBROSER HERE IS IT:

```js
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('input[type="text"], textarea').each (
        function(index){  
            var field = $(this).attr("id");
            $(this).val(localStorage.getItem(field));
        }
    );

    $('input[type="radio"]').each(
        function(index){  
            var field = $(this).attr("name");
            if(localStorage.getItem(field)) {
                var value = localStorage.getItem(field);
                $("[id='"+value+"']").prop('checked',true);
            }
        }
    );

    $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(
        function(index){  
            var field = $(this).attr("name");
            if(localStorage.getItem(field)) {
                var value = localStorage.getItem(field);
                $("[id='"+value+"']").prop('checked',true);
            }
        }
    );

    $('input[type="text"], textarea').on('input', function() {
        var Uniq = $(this).attr("id");
        var Content = $(this).val();
            localStorage.setItem(Uniq, Content);
    });

    $('input:radio').on('change', function() {
        var Uniq = $(this).attr("name");
        var Content = $(this).attr("id");
            localStorage.setItem(Uniq, Content);
    });

    $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
        var Uniq = $(this).attr("name");
        var Content = $(this).attr("id");
            localStorage.setItem(Uniq, Content);
    });
  });
```